# How to auto config mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

I want to create a MongoDB replica set, and according to the documentation I need to run sth like this in my first mongo instance in order to config the replica set and this works fine. However, I was wondering if there is a way to automate this process and don't ssh to the server and run this piece of code every time. I tried putting it in a config file but it didn't work

```
rs.initiate( {
 _id : "rs0",
 members: [
    { _id: 0, host: "mongodb0.example.net:27017" },
    { _id: 1, host: "mongodb1.example.net:27017" },
    { _id: 2, host: "mongodb2.example.net:27017" }
  ]
})
```

Comment: No, you need to issue that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about situation where you create replica set(s) with docker, terraform, ... kind of tools?

You can always include local init -script what have that rs.initiate(...) command.

Replica set needs ALWAYS initial initiate -command. Without it, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is a bit old, I think it is important to show a possible solution to future readers!

This repo https://github.com/deRemo/dockerized-mongodb presents a python script to automate the configuration of a replica set in a "dockerized" scenario. Have a look at **configure_rs.py**

Here I extrapolated the important bits:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os,sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("USAGE: ./script ip1 ip2 ... (hostname are also valid, if recognised)")
    exit()

print("Configuring replica set...")

members = []

for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    prio = 1 if i == 1 else 0 #prioritize first member for the primary election
    members.append("{_id: "+str(i-1)+", host: \'"+str(sys.argv[i])+"\', priority: "+str(prio)+"}")

#stringify members and prepare rs config
members = ', '.join(d for d in members)
cfg = "{_id: 'rs0', members: ["+members+"]}"


os.system("./mongo --host "+sys.argv[1]+" --eval \"JSON.stringify(db.adminCommand({'replSetInitiate' : "+cfg+"}))\"")
```

The script takes as input the hostnames of the machines where your mongod instances are deployed (make sure that they are reachable over your network)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).